# For Riemann Hypothesis, many people seek physics intuition, why not for Goldbach Conjecture ?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, mathematical-physics, riemann-hypothesis, goldbachs-conjecture

All:

As we all know,  for Riemann Hypothesis research, many people seek physics intuition, to understand more fundamental reasons why Riemann Hypothesis shall hold.

In this direction, we have Hilbert-Polya conjecture, Montgomery pair correlation, Alain Connes' approach,etc. They are all related to physics. Even Bombieri's April fools joke (in 1997) for Riemann Hypothesis  also talked about that physics played an important role in solving Riemann Hypothesis.

But I am not aware any of similar attempt in relating Goldbach conjecture research with physics. It seems that all attempts for Goldbach conjecture are still in
traditional analytic number theory.

Are you aware any attempt to solve Goldbach conjecture using physics theory ?
If no, why is it ?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.6476 "We show that there is a correspondence between Goldbach conjecture sequences (GCS) and expectation values of the number operator in Fock states" http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.6541 "We also comment on the potential consequences of this result concerning the validity or breakdown of the Goldbach conjecture for large integer numbers."